# Post form without name preferably with JSoup

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I am building an Android app and I want to post a html form that looks like this:

```
 <form onsubmit="ShoutBox.postShout(); $('shout_data').value = ''; return false;">
Shout: <input type="text" id="shout_data" size="50"> - 
<input type="submit" value="Shout Now!" id="shouting-status"></form>
```

I am using Jsoup in the rest of the application and I would preferably use it for this aswell.

I know about the `.data(name, value)` method, but since the html text and button don't have name attributes, that's not working. I can extract the field by using the ids and fill the field with: `Element.val(String val);` But I don't know how to post the form after that. Can anyone help me?

This is the JavaScript code for posting it:

```
postShout: function() {
        message = $("shout_data").value;
        if (message == "") {
            return false;
        }

        $("shouting-status").value = ShoutBox.lang[0];

        postData = "shout_data="+encodeURIComponent(message).replace(/\+/g, "%2B");
        new Ajax.Request('xmlhttp.php?action=add_shout', {method: 'post', postBody: postData, onComplete: function(request) { ShoutBox.postedShout(request); }});
    },
```

Comment: you should analyze javascript's method `ShoutBox.postShout()` because this form seems to be not posting in "normal way"

Comment: I have very little knowledge of JS, but I added the function to the Post

Answer (score 0):

The post is not done via a form submit and post variables but via JavaScript and an XML HTTP request. JSoup is incapable to execute JavaScript. You need a browser that you can remote control. To do this headless in Java *HTMLUnit* is a good choice.

Comment: Oooh okay, sadly, I discovered that HTMLUnit doesn't work well in Android apps. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a equivalent library that works with Android. In this specific case I would check if the site policy allows a direct call to the XML HTTP request endpoint; you probably need some cookies set from a login. You can do that manually with the HTTP client.